# Remove ListView Item on CustomAdapter control onClick in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-adapter

I am using `Custom Adapter` to bind `ListView`. Custom `ListView` contains `TextView`, 'Spinner' and `ImageButton`. Everything is working fine.
Now, `onImageButtonClickListener` I want to remove that particular item from `ListView`. I have `position` of item when Click on `ImageButton`. I have also code to remove data from `ArrayList`. But I don't know how to remove item from `ListView`.
As I have checked, It removes item from `ArrayList` but it does not affect anything to `ListView`.
Please help me. Is there any way by which I call `ListView` of Class File in `Custom Adapter` ??? I tried by making object of Class File but It shows `nullpointerException`.
**My Code :**

```
Custom Adapter {
imgDelete.setTag(position);
imgDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        data.remove((Integer) v.getTag());

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Did you call notifydatasetchanged() after removing from array list? Post your code

Comment: Will need more code of the adapter .Is the adapter using the same "data" in getCount() method ?

Comment: you can skip setting the position via `setTag()` and use the `getItem(position)`

Comment: @AjitPratapSingh, yes, same.

Answer (score 1):

Remove it from the adapter using `adapter.remove()` and then update it using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

**Edit:**
In custom adapter, inside `getView` you write the imageButton `onClick`. There you can use the `remove(getItem(position))`. This will remove the element from adapter. Then call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: I am using `ListView onItemClickListener`, I am using 'onClick' of Custom `ListView`'s `ImageButton`. So, How to do this from `Custom Adapter` side.